# Write value from Select in DTO Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have an Entity "User". I have an Enum "Usertyp". Users have a field "usertyp". I want to change the "Usertyp" by passing a DTO to my controller. The problem is that the usertype gets changed to Null in the DB

Another minor problem is that I want the default value of the selectfield to have the users current usertype as default value. I tried with "

```
                        th:selected="${u.usertyp}">
```

and also with an if statement. Neither worked.

I am very grateful for any help. I really struggle with Thymeleaf.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("editUser/{userId}")
public String editUser(@ModelAttribute("sessionUser") User sessionUser, @Valid @ModelAttribute("userDTO") UserDTO userDTO, @PathVariable Long userId, Model model){
    if(sessionUser==null || sessionUser.getUsertyp() == Usertyp.USER)
    {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    else {
        User changedUser = userService.findById(userId);
        changedUser.setUsertyp(Usertyp.fromString(userDTO.getUsertyp()));
        userService.save(changedUser);
        return "redirect:/administration";
    }
}
```

DTO

```
public class UserDTO {
    //TODO usertyp anpassem
    private String usertyp;

    public UserDTO(String usertyp) {
        this.usertyp = usertyp;
    }

    public String getUsertyp() {
        return usertyp;
    }

    public void setUsertyp(String usertyp) {
        this.usertyp = usertyp;
    }
}
```

Template

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <span th:each="u : ${userList}">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span th:text="${u.username}"></span>
        <form th:object="${userDTO}" th:action="@{/editUser/{userId}(userId=${u.id})}" method="Post" id="Rolle">
            <select th:field="*{usertyp}" form="Rolle">
                <option
                        th:each="usertyp : ${T(com.example.myproject.entities.Usertyp).values()}"
                        th:text="${usertyp.displayText}"
                        th:value="${usertyp.displayText}">
                </option>
                </select>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Speichern">
        </form>
    </li>
        </span>
</ul>
```

I already changed my DTO field type from "Usertyp" to String

Answer (score 0):

> th:selected="${u.usertyp}">

The th:selected property should convert to selected="selected" or just selected in raw html, I think instead you want something like `th:selected="${u.usertyp == usertyp}"`

You didn't show your `@GetMapping` setup for the thyme leaf page, so I didn't include a user list, but here's a basic example of what I think you're attempting to do:

User Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("user")
    public String getUserTypePage(@ModelAttribute("userDTO") UserDTO userDTO) {
        // just setting it to admin so that it will show the default selection of not the first item
        userDTO.setUserType(UserType.ADMIN);
        return "user";
    }

    @PostMapping("user")
    public void postUserTypePage(@ModelAttribute("userDTO") UserDTO userDTO) {
        System.out.println("USER DTO TYPE - " + userDTO.getUserType().getDisplayText());
    }
}
```

UserType enum:

```
public enum UserType {
    USER("Standard User"),
    ADMIN("Administrator");

    private final String displayText;
    UserType(String displayText) {
        this.displayText = displayText;
    }

    public String getDisplayText() {
        return displayText;
    }
}
```

UserDTO:

```
public class UserDTO {
    private UserType userType;

    public UserDTO(UserType userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public UserType getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>User Type</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <form th:object="${userDTO}" th:action="@{/user}" method="POST" id="Rolle">
            <select th:field="*{userType}" form="Rolle">
                <option
                        th:each="uType : ${T(com.example.demo.models.UserType).values()}"
                        th:text="${uType.displayText}"
                        th:value="${uType}"
                        th:selected="${userType == uType}">
                </option>
                </select>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Speichern">
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Specifically you want the th:value to be bound to the enum value (if you'd prefer to use an enum rather than a string):

> th:value="${uType}"

And then the th:selected set based off of equality of the enum to the UserType option in being looped through:

> th:selected="${userType == uType}">

A few additional things to check:

1. Are you establishing the @ModelAttribute("userDTO") in the GET variant of your controller?
2. Log out the value of the userType in your post method to confirm it's value before any database operation (to confirm that it is actually coming in as null from the post and not being set to null somewhere in the db operation).
3. Try just passing along the value for the userType in the form (instead of using a select input item) to confirm that the currentValue for your model is getting fed through i.e.: `<input th:field="*{userType}" th:value="${userType}">`